# Fixed the rogue bracket at the end, but the tabbing here still makes it a little odd. At least it's not as obvious

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I am new to android app development. I wrote some code for `checkbox` but I’m not getting expected result. All the `checkboxes` are displayed on same line. How do I display each `checkbox` on separate line?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_bike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Bike"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_car"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Car"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_office"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Office"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Home"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_locker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Locker"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view){
    boolean checked=((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.chechbox_bike:
        if (checked)
            System.out.println("bike");
    case R.id.chechbox_car:
        if (checked)
            System.out.println("Car");
    case R.id.chechbox_home:
        if (checked)
            System.out.println("Home");
    case R.id.chechbox_locker:
        if (checked)
            System.out.println("Locker");
    case R.id.chechbox_office:
        if (checked)
            System.out.println("Office");
    }       
}
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are attributes like `layout_toLeftOf` or `layout_below`. Use them with the id of the referenced checkbox.

For example:

```
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_bike"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Bike"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/chechbox_car"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Car"
    android:layout_below="@id/checkbox_bike"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

See the attribute `android:layout_below="@id/checkbox_bike"` I added to the second checkbox.

A short explanation: A relative layout is used to place views in "relation" to each other. Without any information they are always at the top left corner.

You could also change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. In this you define an orientation (vertical or horizontal) and each new view will be placed below or to the right side of the previous one (depending on the orientation of the LinearLayout).